# Modeling Related Question

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to model this piece?

I  am new to blender, I have tried many times but failed to get this shape of the piece especially the curve  inside the mesh.

[image]

Its a sniper model the name is Ai AS50  and here is what I have done so far as i wanted to block out this piece I have attached my work as well as the reference that I am using

[image]

Comment: Hello. You should show what you've tried so far. From that, one here may help going further if you have some difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use boolean operations to model the curved insets on the gun that you circled:

if you have a solid part of the gun:

[image: start]

Model a second object that is the shape you want your inset to be:

[image: mid]

Position your second object to overlap your gun. Then add a boolean modifier set to difference to the gun shape, and select the second object. After hiding the second object, you will easily get a curved inset:

[image: final]